# Is there a way to reset my iphone 4 to fix this problem

Tags: iphone

All of a sudden, my Voice Control on my iphone 4 keeps beeping and making noises, and it's starting songs on the music player and making the whole phone go haywire.

I turned the phone off and on again but the problem persists. Is there a way to replace the whole system or do something else that might fix it

The phone was working perfectly yesterday and every other day since last October when I bought it

Comment: does the home button work?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a reset is probably the most likely thing to fix this. It will reset your iPhone to factory settings, and then put back your settings and media from a backup.

You can rest your iPhone by connecting it to iTunes, selecting it in the sidebar, going to the General tab, and clicking Restore.

Take a look at the Restoring Your iPhone section of this [Apple support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414) for more info.

Comment: Even better would be to restore the device and set it up as a new device. Name it differently in iTunes to ensure you don't overwrite the "true" backup. Do a short test of voice control without your settings and data to ensure the hardware button isn't causing the issue. Either way, you can put the "true" backup on your existing phone or one with a repaired button.

Answer (score 1):

Before you go down the full Restore route double check that restoring it to basic content and settings (Settings -> General -> Reset) doesn't help. It's fixed a few things for me before.